# Is it possible to provide "Others" as option, which should always be shown as auto-suggestion, for ANTD Search

Tags: antd

Is it possible to provide "Others" as option for ANTD Search element, which should always be shown as auto-suggestion, irrespective of the search text entered and when we select 'Others' from Select box, a page should open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the value of the "Others" option appropriately as well as modifying your `filterOption` function. Something like this:

```js
let options = [
        <Option 
            value="a"
            key="a"
        >
            a
        </Option>,
        <Option 
            value="b"
            key="b"
        >
            b
        </Option>,
        <Option 
            value="c"
            key="c"
        >
            c
        </Option>,
        <Option 
            value="***control"
            key="***control"
        >
            Others
        </Option>,
];

...

<Select
    onChange={value => value !== "***control" ? setChosenOption(value) : openSomePageOrModal()}
    showSearch
    value={chosenOption}
    filterOption={(input, option) => (option.props.value === "***control") ||
        option.props.children.includes(input)
    }
    >
    <Option value="" key="">Select an option</Option>
    {options}
    </Select>
```